# Trying to populate html table with ng-repeat using two different arrays

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having some issues trying to populate a table with two arrays.  I am trying to achieve the following output:

[image]

I have an array called `students` and within each student object, I have a `courses` array.  I am trying to populate my table using `ng-repeat` to show all courses against each student.

Not all data is given within each course, meaning that if a student hasn't started a course then it won't appear in the `courses` array.  Also, if a student hasn't finished a course there will be no date completed given.

So my array looks like so:

```
$scope.students = [
    {
        Id: 1,
        Name: 'Joe Blogs',
        Courses: [
            {
                Title: 'Course 1',
                Grade: 87,
                Completed: true,
                DateCompleted: '2018-01-01'
            },
            {
                Title: 'Course 2',
                Grade: 2,
                Completed: false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        Id: 2,
        Name: 'Peter Smith',
        Courses: [
            {
                Title: 'Course 1',
                Grade: 100,
                Completed: true,
                DateCompleted: '2018-01-01'
            },
            {
                Title: 'Course 2',
                Grade: 95,
                Completed: true,
                DateCompleted: '2018-01-01'
            },
            {
                Title: 'Course 3',
                Grade: 10,
                Completed: false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        Id: 3,
        Name: 'Joanne Someone',
        Courses: [
            {
                Title: 'Course 3',
                Grade: 55,
                Completed: false,
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So far my code snippet looks like this:

```
                <table class="table table-hover" width="100%">

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Course</th>
                            <th>Grade</th>
                            <th>Completed</th>
                            <th>Date Completed</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="student in students">
                            <td>{{ student.Id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ student.Name }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <!-- Can't figure this bit out -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                </table>
```

But I am stuck on how to get multiple courses to show against each student.  Also I have found that by using `ng-repeat`, if a value isn't in the object (e.g. Date Completed) then that field will not show and pushes everything up and out of alignment.

Lastly, I will mention that I am using angular-datatables however, I am just trying to work out the concept, then I can apply this to datatables later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use `rowspan` for that purpose. And the value of that for particular Id should be of length of `Courses`. Then, you'll need to have ng-repeat on tbody to repeat tbody section & have ng-repeat inside on tr for repeating `Courses` arrays of each student. So, your table view code can be:

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Course</td>
    <td>Grade</td>
    <td>Completed</td>
    <td>Date Completed</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody ng-repeat="x in students">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="{{x.Courses.length}}"><span>{{ x.Id }}</span></td>
    <td rowspan="{{x.Courses.length}}"><span>{{ x.Name }}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{x.Courses[0].Title}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{x.Courses[0].Grade}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{x.Courses[0].Completed}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{x.Courses[0].DateCompleted}}</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in x.Courses" ng-if="$index > 0">
    <td><span>{{item.Title}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{item.Grade}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{item.Completed}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{item.DateCompleted}}</span></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

To avoid breaking of table code if some values are not available, just have it inside `span` element so it'll still load `td` with no value inside it.

[**Plunker Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/TM1gNPQJ0MXxiprYs9x3?p=preview)

Comment: You're an absolute superstar!  Thank you so much and that example helps me understand it for future reference.

Comment: Yes true, but I wanted to tap into datatables export to csv functionality, hence why I ventured down this path.